# Разница между php middle и senior developer

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Если с junior все ясно (стажер), то как понять, где грань между middle и senior?
Как понять к какому уровню относятся работники, я?

Comment: Разница в зарплате.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Когда нормальный проджект менеджер боится с Вами спорить чтобы не опростоволоситься - это Вы сеньйор, а когда просто советуется - это миддле :-)

Comment: Нормальный проджект-менеджер -- такое бывает? (Мой папа вам завидует.)

Comment: Бывают :-) Я например :-D Но в данном случае нормальный я имел в виду технически грамотный а не просто политически назначеный. Второй всегда будет боятся спорить даже с джуниором.

Comment: Это все круто, лол. Но как определить уровень при приеме на работу?

Comment: По резюме, а потом на испытательном сроке по лолу? :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Senior` - Обычно это тот, у кого огромный опыт за плечами, тот, кто разрабатывает ключевые компоненты системы. И тим лидер, который собственно и занимается техническим руководством команды.

`Middle` - тот, который также имеет достаточно большой опыт, но не дотягивает до знаний senior'a. И, конечно же, сможет поставить себе задачу.

Советоваться может любой разработчик, так что ответ [[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)'а считаю не правильным.

Comment: Туд дело не в разработчике - а проджект менеджере. Разработчики то вечно советуються

Comment: А как понять - что не дотягивает по знаниям?

Comment: Вы не учли, что менеджера проектов может вообще не быть :)

Comment: Ну, тогда обычно и деления на сеньйора и мидля не делаеться. Когда проджект менеджера нету, тогда и проекта нету :-) Так - баловство...

Answer (score 0):

Есть у некоторых компаний градации такие. Помню что на сениор пхп нужно было иметь опыт работы с хайлоад проектами. Опыт такой соответственно где попало или дома не получишь.

Answer (score -5):

Сеньоров под похапе не бывает - есть только:

- джуниоры: кто только-только начал
     кодировать.
- МиддлЫ: те кто что-то может и уже понял что в PHP ловить нечего и вот-вот
     свалит.

Comment: Сеньёр пых :-) Вполне себе...